# exporting nest js middleware to another project

Tags: node.js, nestjs, middleware

I'm trying to export a custom middleware project in NestJS to all my other projects(and import this in all of them). My actual class is `acl-jwt.middleware.ts` in its bootstrap `src` folder.

In the `acl-jwt.middleware.ts` I have:

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware,  } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AclJwtMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    console.log("ACL JWT Middleware !!")
    next();
  }
}
```

and my `app.module.ts` has:

```
import { Module, NestModule, MiddlewareConsumer, RequestMethod } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AclJwtMiddleware } from './acl-jwt.middleware';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(AclJwtMiddleware).forRoutes({ path: '*', method: RequestMethod.ALL });
  }
}
```

And in my another project's `app.module.ts`, I'm importing this like the following

```
import { AclJwtMiddleware } from 'mi';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(AclJwtMiddleware).forRoutes({ path: '*', method: RequestMethod.ALL });
  }
}
```

`mi` is my hosted package.

And then when I run my second project, I get the following error:

```
src/app.module.ts:16:34 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mi' or its corresponding type declarations.

16 import { AclJwtMiddleware } from 'mi';
```

Am I not exporting something? Or am I not importing it properly?

I've been searching all over the internet but I couldn't find something with my use case. Any help would be really good. Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to make sure that in your `package.json` of your `mi` package, you have either `main` or `files` that points to the properly exported file/directory. If it is a barrel file, like `index.js`, then you need to make sure it exports the middleware properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This saved me a lot of time. I just needed to export it the right way!